# Custom error handler in Zone.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, zonejs

I've been working with Zone.js and I want to set up logging for any uncaught exceptions. I could set up an error handler, like so:

```
window.onerror = function(e) { 
    //send an error report to the server
}
```

But this won't work if an exception is thrown inside a Promise. The nice thing about the Zone error handler is that it hooks into Promises and does fire for exceptions in them, but I can't find a way to actually override or add an error handler after the Zone has been created aside from overriding a bunch of private fields on the Zone.

Is there an actual API for a Zone that I can use to update the error handler, or do I have to change the polyfill where the root Zone is constructed or overwrite private fields or something similar?

Comment: You can save reference to `Promise` constructor before executing Zone.js script.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 I don't see how that helps me.

Answer (score 3):

for promise uncaught promise error, from zone.js 0.78, you can use this API.

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/627

```
 window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function (event) {
  console.warn("WARNING: Unhandled promise rejection. Shame on you! Reason: "
               + event.reason);
});

window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", function (event) {
  console.log("Promise rejected! Reason: " + reason);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js?main=browser"></script>
<script>
Zone.current.fork({
    onHandleError: function(parentZoneDelegate, currentZone, targetZone, error) {
        console.log("Error handled by zone: " + error);
    }
}).run(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("In zone setTimeout")
        throw new Error("Throw in zone setTimeout"); 
    }, 0);
    console.log("Directly in zone");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Which would catch the exception in the custom handler specified by `onHandleError` and yield output like this:

```
Directly in zone (test1.html:14)
In zone setTimeout (test1.html:11 )
Error handled by zone: Error: Throw in zone setTimeout (test1.html:7)
```

However it seems it does not work if exceptions are thrown directly in the zone. I have filed and [issue](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/429) about this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `runGuarded` method instead of `run` on Zone if you want to handle all types of unhandled exceptions (in simple zones, in setTimeouts or in Promises, etc.)

Here is a sample code to do that:

```
Zone.current.fork({
  name: 'MyGlobalErrorLoggerZone',
  onHandleError: function(parentZoneDelegate, currentZone, targetZone, error){
     console.log(error);
     // send it to server here.
  }
})
.runGuarded(function(){
   // your application code here...
   // handles errors inside promises
   new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject('Rejecting: Some Error');
   });
    console.log('Running in Zone...', Zone.current.name);
    // handles errors inside timeouts/intervals
    setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('after 1 sec', Zone.current.name);
            throw new Error('This is an error. Make your self log me please.');
    }, 1000);
    // Handles errors throw directly in zone too.
    throw new Error('oops, one more error');
});
```